# Printing an unwanted alphabet "s" on top of my blog website.

Tags: php, wordpress

friends on WordPress blog website an unwanted alphabet "s" is printing. it prints after starting of a  tag. I am unable to find out the source of this "s". it does not print into any HTML tag so that I could hide it.Please help me how to get rid of this bug.For your reference,[image of "s"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2mGn.jpg) I am adding an image as well.

Comment: It prints just after body tag

Comment: supply some code

Comment: Just look into the source code, that's where you will find it. I think you must have tried to save something using Shift - s instead of Ctrl-s and hence the Capital S.

Comment: Agreed with @MaharshiRawal but If you aren't able to debug source code then you can usually hide through CSS/jQuery too.

Comment: Also can you please provide blog URL to us so that we can check and let you know?

Comment: this is blog URL: https://www.staging9.ascendviral.com/testing/

Comment: provide functions.php code and header.php code

Comment: @HarvinderSingh
Please provide some code only after that anyone can find the unwanted alphabet  's'  and provide you to the best answer

Answer (score 2):

In your coding while  you are entering this `<script type="text/javascript">var ajaxurl = "https://www.staging9.ascendviral.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"</script>`

you have accidentally added "S" after the  script tag remove that S

`<script type="text/javascript">var ajaxurl = "https://www.staging9.ascendviral.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"</script>`**S** <- from here.